# Passing JS function to applet for as event listener

Tags: java, javascript, events, applet

Is it possible to pass a function/callback from javascript to a java applet?

For example i have an applet with a button that when pressed it will call the passed js callback

```
function onCommand() {
  alert('Button pressed from applet');
}
applet.onCommand(onCommand);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to use something I derived from the reflection example at the bottom of [this page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0172.html), as then you don't need to meddle with your classpath to get it to compile

Then I just pass JSON strings around between the applet and javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JSObject](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html) to call back into javascript from Java.

From that page:

```
import netscape.javascript.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
class MyApplet extends Applet {
     public void init() {
         JSObject win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
         JSObject doc = (JSObject) win.getMember("document");
         JSObject loc = (JSObject) doc.getMember("location");

         String s = (String) loc.getMember("href");  // document.location.href
         win.call("f", null);                      // Call f() in HTML page
     }
}
```

Comment: is it also possible to pass js function which is an object as the first argument of win.call instead the name of the js function?

Comment: No, but instead of passing in the bare callback function you could create a new object containing it, pass that in then use the object.call(name) form.

Answer (score 3):

ps. to use  JSObject you may need to include "MAYSCRIPT" tag to applet html tag.